# Is it possible to create Service Fabric Container Service based on a saved image (TAR file)?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, containers, azure-service-fabric

Our customer runs a Service Fabric cluster onprem with servers not allowed to access the internet. I' trying to create a container service for Service Fabric using Visual Studio 2017. In the wizard for creating a new project there is an option to provide an Image Name of the container. Many examples points to Docker Hub Repository.
So I'm looking for a way to develop and deploy a container service without internet access. Is there a way to point to my own container image (local TAR file) during project creation?

Comment: Found a solution.

Comment: The trick was to manually transfer the container image and the just reference the image in the service fabric application. On building the sf app, it first look in the local repository and when its there no internet access is required.
Steps on internet connected computer:
docker search [name of image]
docker pull [name of image]
docker save [name of image] -o C:\temp\my_image.tar
-> Transfer tar to internet-disconnected system
docker load -i C:\temp\my_image.tar
Here you can build a sf app with (web) reference to the (locally available) image.
Done.